# Move in the direction the VR window is pointing

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am trying to make it so that the CardboardMain in Unity will slowly drift in the direction that the center point of the VR is pointing. I have the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
    public float balloon_speed = 0.0001f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
        //transform.Rotate (0, rotLeftRight, 0);
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0,0,balloon_speed);
        direction = transform.rotation * direction;
        transform.localPosition += direction;
    }
}
```

If the lines

```
//float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
//transform.Rotate (0, rotLeftRight, 0);
```

are un-commented, the script works perfectly in Unity.  When I load it to an android device, the camera will drift forwards and the direction won't change. I think the reason for this is that the VR coordinates are different from what transform.rotaion will return. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
void Update() {
    transform.localPosition += balloon_speed * Vector3.forward;
}
```

I think in your script you were adding a world-coordinate vector (rotation * direction) to the local-coordinate position.